# Register github runner at organization level programmatically

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I want to provision an EC2 instance on AWS as a self-hosted runner.

I managed to do so with the following command:

```
./config.sh --url https://github.com/Org/repo --pat XXXXX
```

This worked fine when using the particular runner for `https://github.com/Org/repo`

How can I do the same for an entire org? Does the `pat` need to have some special permissions?
What value should I pass to the url?

Comment: Please provide reference to the `./config.sh` command-line, e.g. the manual page you obtained it from.